# CUPS page_log is always empty

Tags: printing

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 as a basic CUPS server.

The problem is that `/var/log/cups/page_log` is always empty.

`cupsd.conf`

```
PageLogFormat %p %u %j %T %P %C %{job-billing} %{job-originating-host-name} %{job-name} %{media} %{sides}
```

`cups-files.conf`

```
PageLog /var/log/cups/page_log
```

I have tried on another Ubuntu 15.10 machine  too with same problem. `access_log` and `error_log` are used. If I put debug output on, the `error_log` grows huge, but there is nothing about `page_log` in there.

Permissions are the same on `access_log`, `error_log` and `page_log`

Any ideas on how to enable CUPS to log all printouts in `page_log`?

Comment: In my case, `page_log` didn't exist and the PageLogSetting was empty; after using your PageLogFormat setting and restarting the cups service, it worked for me, i.e. the `page_log` file was created including entries.